# Where IN query on Doctrine ManyToMany tags relation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

A little bit of background:

- I've got Office entities.
- Offices may have articles.
- Articles have tags.
- Offices can share a tag with other offices (and therefore articles).

Now I'm trying to build a query that says: "Fetch all articles that either belong to my office or have tags that have been shared with my office".

I've tried this in **MySQL** and the following query works as expected:

```
SELECT 
    *  
FROM 
    `articles` `a` 
WHERE 
    (
        `office_id` = 2 
        OR 
        `a`.`id` IN (
            SELECT 
                `at`.`article_id` 
            FROM 
                `article_tags` `at` 
            WHERE 
                `at`.`article_id` = `a`.`id` 
            AND 
                `at`.`tag_id` IN 
                (
                    SELECT 
                        `st`.`tag_id` 
                    FROM 
                        `shared_tags` `st` 
                    WHERE 
                        `st`.`shared_with_id` = 2 
                    AND 
                        `st`.`article` = 1
                )
            )
    ) 
AND 
    `status` = 1
```

My entities are as follows:

## Article

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="articles")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="article_tags")
 * @var ArrayCollection|Tag[]
 */
protected $tags;
```

## Tag

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="tags")
 * @var ArrayCollection|Article[]
 */
protected $articles;
```

## SharedTag

```
class SharedTag extends Entity
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Office", inversedBy="sharedTags")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shared_with_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var Office
     */
    protected $sharedWith;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Office", inversedBy="sharedTags")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shared_by_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var Office
     */
    protected $sharedBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="sharedTags")
     * @var Tag
     */
    protected $tag;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default" = 0})
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $template = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default" = 0})
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $article = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Embedded(class = "\ValueObjects\CreatedAt", columnPrefix=false)
     * @var CreatedAt
     */
    protected $createdAt;

}
```

So, how can I query this in DQL or with the QueryBuilder? I've tried several methods but I can't seem to use the `tag_id` from the relationship `articles.tags` in a WHERE IN() query.

Thank you in advance!

---

## Edit:

After some trial and error and thanks to Jean's answer I was able to query it like this:

```
SELECT
  a
FROM
  Article a
LEFT JOIN a.tags t
LEFT JOIN a.office o
LEFT JOIN o.sharedTags st
WHERE
  (
    a.office = :office
    OR
    (
      t = st.tag
      AND
      st.sharedWith = :office
      AND
      st.article = 1
    )
  )
AND
  a.status.status = :status
AND
  a.template IS NULL
GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a join and not subqueries. This way you have better performance and less complicated DQL code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `a`
FROM `articles` `a` 
LEFT JOIN `a.tags` `t`
LEFT JOIN `t.shared_with_id` `o`
WHERE (`a`.`office_id` = 2 OR `o`.`id` = 2) 
AND `status` = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! It goes in the right way however it still needs some extra restrictions. The tags from the article `t` needs to match a tag in the shared tags table (and that shared tag needs to have the boolean `article` set to 1). So I still need to find a way to query with `a.tags.id` somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... This query already filters by shared tags, because the `o.id = 2` condition imposes that the tag is used in the office with ID 2... What else do you need?

Comment: Yes, you are right! There are conditions in place but with some tweaking I found the right ones for my use case, I've updated my question with the working DQL.